# Analysis and data processing On las file using point cloud library

Tags: c++, gis, arcgis, point-cloud-library, lidar

I have **.las data** and i want to do analysis on it  and i want to use Features of   **POINT CLOUD Library** for this . can any body tell me how to covert **.las file to .pcd or any other suitable fie format**  so i can use the newly created file/format in **POINT CLOUD Library**  for analysis
here is details step

1) i have .las file and want to convert this to suitable format (.pcd or any other ) so i can use points cloud features
2) use point cloud library features to show Show    point   cloud   data    in  a   data    viewer  user    can perform following

```
2.1operations   in  data    viewer. 
2.2) Zoom   In/Out
```

Comment: I would appreciate feedback on why you undid the edit. Did I miss an important aspect of what you were trying to ask?

Comment: Thanks Actually Erica  Its is little  new kind of thing  my question is about creating not using Lib las
V Sorry for late reply i was busy and just see ur message

Comment: My edit wasn't about liblas, I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at liblas https://www.liblas.org/

Here is an usage example: http://www.pcl-users.org/Creating-pcd-from-las-files-with-rgb-values-using-laslib-td4028505.html

Comment: You seem to confuse liblas with laslib. These are different libraries.

Comment: oh !  can you just tell me with your experience how to use point cloud library with ".las   file format" file ?

Comment: Actually @KjMag My end goal is to use 
".las file" with  point cloud features i.e 
1) . filteration  2). Visualization    
Because Point cloud mostly uses ".pcd file format"

Comment: Just learn how to use liblas or laslib to read the las file, then write it as a pcd file. Point Cloud Library has documentation regarding how to write to a pcd file. You've got all the pieces - it's enough to use them.